I'm using nginx and I can access my website with ip but not with domain
I'm using nginx and I can access my website with ip but not with domain.Did I set it up or do something wrong? This is my nginx setup.
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    # SSL configuration
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /home/ubuntu/mypro-be.compa.app.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/mypro-be.compa.app.key;

    server_name mypro-be.compa.app;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        root /var/www/mypro-be.compa.app;
        index index.html;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}

I have my domain set to point to my IP.

Where is your domain setup?

You need to narrow down the problem. Is the request reaching your server? Check your Nginx access log.

A couple of suggestions:

use nginx -t to reset the nginx config (refresh any changes).
ensure your firewall is open to traffic on ports 80 and 443

